# Prove that negation of the continuum hypotheses implies existence of subset of R such that...

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Prove that the negation of the continuum hypothesis implies that there exist $A⊂R$ such that $ℵ_0<|A|<|R|$.

The negation of the hypotheses implies existence of a set B such that $ℵ_0<|B|<|R$|, but how can I create a subset of R from it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The continuum hypothesis is logically equivalent to $\nexists A.\aleph_0<|A|<|R|$. So its negation *is* $\exists A.\aleph_0<|A|<|R|$. The implication trivially follows from $P\implies P$.

Comment: What's your defn of $|A|\leq |B|$?

Comment: @R.Burton but I want that A will be a subset of R

Comment: How do you phrase CH here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $ℵ_1 = R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big HINT: By definition $|B|<|\Bbb R|$ means that there is an injection $f:B\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought about finding bijection from the ordinal |A| but this is much more simple.